# how can possible replacing variable value in triple quotation in python/ django with {value}?

Tags: python, django

i'm noob in django/python ,I saw a code in [github](https://gist.github.com/ChrisLTD/5224404) about "exporting Vcard" files , my question is about a part that programmer replace variable value in string variable :

admin.py:

```
output = ""
  for person in queryset.all():
    person_output = """BEGIN:VCARD  
VERSION:3.0
N:{last_name};{first_name}
FN:{first_name} {last_name}
TEL;TYPE=HOME,VOICE:{phone}
TEL;TYPE=WORK,VOICE:{secondary_phone}
EMAIL:{email}
REV:{rev}
END:VCARD"""
    # how can replace value when the source is string?!
    person_output = person_output.format(  
                        first_name = person.first_name, 
                        last_name = person.last_name,
                        phone = person.phone,
                        secondary_phone = person.secondary_phone,
                        email = person.email,
                        rev = d.strftime('%Y%M%d%H%f'),
                        )
```

can anyone plz explain how it possible and let me know any python/django documentation about it?thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just simple [*string formatting* [pyformat]](https://pyformat.info/). One can specify a string according to the format as is explained in the [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#string-formatting) and in [PEP-3101](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3101/) and then by calling `my_string.format(..)` you replace certain parts in the string with other parts.

The fact that it isa string in between "triple quotation" does not make any difference, since it is just a string.

The entire format is explained in PEP-3101, but in short if you write `{var_name}` and then you format it with a named argument `.format(var_name=value)`, then `{var_name}` is replaced by `value`. There are however some exceptions, for example `{{}}` is replaced by `{}`, and the format allows you to align numbers properly, etc.

Since [python-3.6](/questions/tagged/python-3.6), one can use [*f-strings* [real Python]](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/) to perform formatting more effectively.

Comment: thanks. i can't vote up since i haven't enough reputation.